# Email field in user class and spring security ui plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I've got a problem with spring security ui plugin. I'm trying to add an email field to my SecUser class (which stores information about users). However there is no field "email" in Spring Security Management Console generated with s2ui-override. On the other hand, due to documentation this is avaible([link](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/2%20User%20Management.html)):

> By default only the standard fields (username, enabled, accountExpired, accountLocked, and passwordExpired) are available but this is customizable with the grails s2ui-override script - see the section on configuration.

I try to use s2ui overide scripts but with no effect. 
I think this is somethink simple but after hours I can't find solution myself. So if anyone know how to do this - please tell me ;)

At the and my user class:

```
class SecUser {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    String email
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
        email blank: false, email:true
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<SecRole> getAuthorities() {
        SecUserSecRole.findAllBySecUser(this).collect { it.secRole } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "User - "+username;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same question. It seems that the gsps have to be modified manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the source code from [user/edit](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-ui/blob/master/grails-app/views/user/edit.gsp) view:

```
    <table>
    <tbody>

        <s2ui:textFieldRow name='username' labelCode='user.username.label' bean="${user}"
                        labelCodeDefault='Username' value="${user?.username}"/>

        <s2ui:passwordFieldRow name='password' labelCode='user.password.label' bean="${user}"
                            labelCodeDefault='Password' value="${user?.password}"/>

        <s2ui:checkboxRow name='enabled' labelCode='user.enabled.label' bean="${user}"
                       labelCodeDefault='Enabled' value="${user?.enabled}"/>

        <s2ui:checkboxRow name='accountExpired' labelCode='user.accountExpired.label' bean="${user}"
                       labelCodeDefault='Account Expired' value="${user?.accountExpired}"/>

        <s2ui:checkboxRow name='accountLocked' labelCode='user.accountLocked.label' bean="${user}"
                       labelCodeDefault='Account Locked' value="${user?.accountLocked}"/>

        <s2ui:checkboxRow name='passwordExpired' labelCode='user.passwordExpired.label' bean="${user}"
                       labelCodeDefault='Password Expired' value="${user?.passwordExpired}"/>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

There are not *email* field. You should to copy the edit.gsp and create.gsp files from source to grails-app/views/user/ and edit it pasting this code after *username* field:

```
    <s2ui:textFieldRow name='email' labelCode='user.email.label' bean="${user}"
                    labelCodeDefault='email' value="${user?.email}"/>
```

You must to create a *spring-security-core-local.properties* in grails-app/i18n/ path and to write the new property

```
user.email.label=Email
```

And of course, you should to create the property *email* in the correct domain class.